# Scope of __declspec allocations

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In C++, I am interested in declaring a pointer variable as read-only, and I am considering to do that via the following mechanism:

```
#pragma section (".readonly", read)
__declspec(allocate(".readonly"))
VOID* g_pROData; // I want this to be read-only

VOID* g_pRWData; // I want this to be read-write
```

However, I am not sure about the scope of the __declspec statement. Would it include only g_pROdata, or would it include g_pRWData too? Is there any way to alter the scope?

Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with `const`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `const` is not guaranteed to be read-only - you can (often) cast a pointer to a const data item and write to it. Sometimes you can't, and it's undefined behaviour to actually do so, but UB is not a guarantee of any meaningful behaviour, as you probably already know.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: that sounds reasonable, except the OP is using visual c++ specific directives. and for visual c++ ["The default segment in the .obj file for const variables is .rdata"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dc22465.aspx), where as I understand rdata by default is a read-only section.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. It's several years since I last programmed on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full syntax is:

```
 __declspec(allocate("segname")) declarator
```

So it applies only to declaration that follows, in your case only `g_pROData` is *affected* and allocated in segment named `.readonly`. If more that one variable needs to be allocated in that segment then you have to repeat declaration for each one.

Comment: @lancery I suppose you know but: all variables allocated in a read-only section will be read-only. Forever because read-only is forced by section (not by compiler where you just have a poor weak const modifier).

Comment: You know the Standard allows you to put constant global variables in a readonly section, right?

Comment: @DeadMG yes, of course any declarator can be applied. What I mean is that a variable (const or not) in a read-only section can't be modified (or "overridden").

Answer (score 0):

A `__declspec` is always directly coupled to the "object" that it is immediately before.

However, are you sure you want to have a `void *` that is read only? what on earth good is that, you can't even set the pointer to something. Did you mean that you want your pointer to point to a readonly section? Or at the very least, an initialization, e.g. `VOID* g_pROData = ...`