# Prohibit inclusion of incompatible headers across compilation units

Tags: c++

This is a theoretical question: Assume you have a library and it has two headers. Is there any possibility with C++ or with preprocessor macros or a combination of both to achieve the following behaviour:

1. Dependent projects *can* include Header 1 **or** Header 2 in any number of compilation units without error.
2. Dependent Projects *cannot* include both Headers even if its accross different compilation units.

I'd like to have some construct that would result in some kind of error (e.g. a linker error) for the 2nd case. I does not need to give a nice error message, I just want to prohibt inclusion of two incompatible headers in the same dependent project. Is that possible?

**EXAMPLE:**

*Header1.h*

```
// type definitions for foo, Version 1
...
```

*Header2.h*

```
// type definitions for foo, Version 2
...
```

*Scenario 1:*

```
// (linker) error, versions do not match
CompilationUnit1.cpp <-- Header1.h
CompilationUnit2.cpp <-- Header2.h
```

*Scenario 2:*

```
// ok, versions match
CompilationUnit1.cpp <-- Header2.h
CompilationUnit2.cpp <-- Header2.h
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible!

Comment: @Eva do you have any restriction about compiler? There is a way but it's not portable.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. Preprocessor macro's are applied on a per-TU basis. The only linker error that's reliably generated is "undefined symbol" and that's not caused by including _more_ headers. ODR violations are the next most obvious candidate, even though not formally diagnosable. These fail because two TU's may here include the same header.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: We mostly use Visual Studio 2013, but some (very few) projects need to be built with gcc as well.

Comment: If you also write the lib, then there's probably a way. Create a global int (or a fancier sigleton) in the lib. Provide extern decls for it in both headers. Let each header have a static object which is initialized with a function checking the global's value and then setting it. Each header has its own idea about the correct one. If it's wrong, bingo.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: I tried to come up with something like this myself, but whatever I tried it didn't work. Could you post it as an answer and provide an example? Also, what you suggest would give an error at build time or at run time?

Comment: I just realized -- at run time, which may not be what you want. But then, one could as a kludge run the prog (with a special command line param) during the build and thus check at "build time", in a way .... similar to what a configure script does to check things.

Comment: @MSalters "duplicate symbol" is not reliable? With the compilers I used (gcc, Sun, irix) I had to use special flags to link with symbol collisions.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: ODR violations are "Undefined Behavior, **no diagnostic required**".

Comment: If a post-build check is allowed, it's simple. Include two TU's in the library, each defining just one string. Reference these strings from the respective headers. If the linker pulls in both strings, both headers were included.

Comment: @MSalters You mean check the resulting executable with `objdump` or the like for the respective symbol? Wouldn't that only work with a statically linked prog?

Comment: @Eva If a VC++ specific solution is viable then I posted my answer. You get just a warning (not an error) unless linking with /WX.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: No, that's why I said "strings".  I.e. `vec.cpp : `const char vec_defined[] = "If you see this string, vec.cpp made it into the library"`. You don't look for `vec_defined" "` , you look for the literal.

Comment: @MSalters I'm missing something. How do I "look for the literal", resp. what do you mean by that?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: On Linux/Unix, `strings a.out | grep "If you see this string, ???.cpp made it into the library" | wc -l`

Comment: @MSalters Ah. Similar to objdump (inspect the executable). Perhaps simpler. I see. Although I understand that the OP doesn't mind having that string in there; she wants *either* that one *or* the other one, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working with Visual C++ then **it can be done** (but be warned that it's not portable and you will get warnings instead of errors unless you use `/WX`). With GCC (maybe, I didn't try) you may use somehow `#pragma weak`.

Because each compilation unit is compiled separately then you have to find *something* at linker level (exporting a function, changing a setting). Easiest way I found is to declare a section and allocate a dummy variable on it. If this section is declared with different attributes on your headers then linker will complain.

You have to add this to **Header1.h**:

```
#pragma section("mylib_priv_impl_section",read)
__declspec(allocate("mylib_priv_impl_section")) static int mylib_priv_impl_var = 0;
```

And then in **Header2.h**:

```
#pragma section("mylib_priv_impl_section",read,write)
__declspec(allocate("mylib_priv_impl_section")) static int mylib_priv_impl_var = 0;
```

Now when you compile and link you will get this warning:

> multiple 'mylib_priv_impl_section' sections found with different attributes (C0300040)

Because we declared same section with different attributes (`read` in Header1 and `read+write` in Header2). Unfortunately it's just a warning (you may use section name to give some useful diagnostic message) and to stop compilation you must specify `/WX` (unfortunately ignored by `#pragma comment(linker, "/WX")`).

Note that we need that *dummy* variable otherwise  our declared section (if unused) will be simply ignored. Nothing else but our dummy variable will be placed in that section (see also [Scope of __declspec allocations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23416861/1207195)).

---

Note that if a preprocessor macro is viable then also a solution similar to what [Marco Giordano](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34925398/1207195) suggested will work smoothly. I'd just change the way it work to throw an error if you're including Header1 but you set you want to use Version2 (and vice-versa) instead of having a macro for inclusion. Something like this (in Header1 and specular in Header2):

```
#if MyLibVersion != 1
#error You are including version 1 headers, please set MyLibVersion accordingly.
#endif
```

Comment: Right now I like your solution best, But I'm not too familiar with sections. As I understand it, the above lines will change the section attributes for the whole translation unit - won't messing around with this put me in danger of segmentation faults or other strange/undefined run time behaviour? Also, I would probably need this for more than two headers, so I'd probably use other attributes as well (execute, shared, nopage etc.).

Comment: @eva no, it will change section only for that variable (that's why it's there: if section is unused then compiler will just ignore our directive)

Comment: You can use same attributes (to do not make maintenance a nightmare) but different sections. Just include header name in section name (even just using __FILE__ macro)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: Are you sure, it's only for one variable? On page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50bewfwa.aspx it says: "Once a section is defined, it remains valid for the remainder of the compilation."

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich yes, it's _defined_. From same paragraph: _"However, you must use __declspec(allocate) or nothing will be placed in the section."_.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I read that too, but as I understand it anything that comes after the __declspec will be put into the same section. It doesn't say that it's limited to only the next variable definition.

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich it is. declspec(allocate) applies only to one _declaration_ (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bkb2w6t.aspx)). See also [Scope of __declspec allocations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23416861/1207195).

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you are talking about generic headers of a library, for example vec.h and mat.h, and for some reason you want to express rules to avoid to have:

```
#include <vec.h>
#include <mat.h>
```

If that is the case I don't think that is possible, on the other hand if you are talking about same header from different library version, like vec_2_0.h , vec_2_1.h I would talke the problem differently (well first of all if I could name the headers I would not write the version on the header itself).

The way I would tackle is by separating the includes in the folder structure example:

```
mathlib:

-----> mathlib_2_0
---------> includes
----> mathlib_2_1
-------->  includes
```

Then you can enforce at project settings to avoid picking one over the other, rather then trying to fix that in the file itself.

Maybe what you can do (but I think is ugly) is to wrap all the possible header include in a macro and use a define version to have the processor leaving only the correct one.
Example:

```
Compiler flag -DMathVersion 2_0
```

The macro:

```
INCLUDE_VECTOR_HEADER()
{
#if MathVersion == 2_0
#include <vec_2_0.h>
#elif MathVersion == 2_1
#include <vec_2_1.h>
#endif
}
```

But I think is way overkill and a bit ugly, maybe can be generalized in having the version as parameter of the macro. I would not go down that road personally.
PS: All is pseudo code just to give an idea

Comment: I like the general idea to prevent it during the build and not with a language mechanism. That may solve the OP's problem, in a way he (and I) didn't think of.

Comment: I see, if you want a "language agnostic" way then maybe with pre-build scripts?
Now I don't know if is possible, it is mainly a wild guess, what you can do is have a python (or other languages) script, parsing the files and check for the rules you want, would not be hard to create a system of generic rules to match the code.
Cons of this approach is the extra time taken at compile time, and if possible to trigger such script, the trigger might be different from compiler to compiler. Again, just wild guess not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

A run time check is doable language-only. (In another post I'll suggest a number of build-time checks.)

This is not elegant. I have a nagging feeling that somebody will come up with a 2-liner for this. But for what it's worth.

Each header defines a class which will be instantiated once for each translation unit when the program starts. (We need a class because we need to run ctor code in order to check a value.) The ctor of each class reads a global `sentinel` and checks whether it has the wrong magic value (it will be 0 initially as a global). If not, it assigns its own. It does not rely on the initialization order of the static objects. I am not sure whether we need to protect sentinel from concurrent access here; I hope not.

lib.cpp (your library):

```
int sentinel;
// other lib stuff
// ...
```

f1.h (one of the two headers):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

extern int sentinel;

struct f1duplGuard
{
    enum { f1=0xf1, f2= 0xf2 };

    f1duplGuard() 
    { 
        cout << "f1 duplGuard() " << endl;
        if( ::sentinel == f2 ) 
        {
            cerr << "f1: include violation -- must be a f2 somewhere" << endl;
            exit(1); 
        }
        sentinel = f1;
    }
};

static f1duplGuard dg;
```

f2.h (the other header -- the moirror image with a different constant):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

extern int sentinel;

struct f2duplGuard
{
    enum { f1=0xf1, f2= 0xf2 };

    f2duplGuard() 
    { 
        cout << "f2 duplGuard() " << endl;

        if( ::sentinel == f1 ) 
        {
            cerr << "f2: include violation -- must be a f1 somewhere" << endl;
            exit(1); 
        }
        sentinel = f2;
    }
};

static f2duplGuard dg;
```

One TU using the lib, including one of the two f headers

```
#include <iostream>
#include "f2.h"      // changing this to f1.h fails at run time

using namespace std;


void f(void)
{
    cout << "second.cpp, f()" << endl;
}
```

The second TU using the lib, including an f header, too (with main):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "f2.h"

extern void f();

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Phew. If you change one of the two includes to the other header, you trigger an error message and exit.

Sample session (without the error):

```
$ g++ -O0 -std=c++14  -o dupl-static -Wall second.cpp dupl-static.cpp lib.cpp && ./dupl-static
f2 duplGuard()
f2 duplGuard()
second.cpp, f()
```

Sample session with error:

```
 cat dupl-static.cpp && g++ -std=c++14  -o dupl-static -Wall second.cpp dupl-static.cpp lib.cpp && ./dupl-static
#include <iostream>
#include "f1.h"

extern void f();

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
        f();
}
f1 duplGuard()
f2 duplGuard()
f2: include violation -- must be a f1 somewhere
```

Comment: I was looking for something that produces a build time error, but after all, a guaranteed run time failure right at the beginning of a run would still do the job. However, I have one question: in your c'tor you access the sentinel variable before it is initialized, don't you? It's very unlikely, but as I see it `::sentinel == f1` could evaluate to `true` even though `::sentinal` has not been initialized... Am I overseeing something or is this undefined behaviour? Anyway, +1 for your efforts!

Comment: No, global variables are "zero-initialized before any other initialization takes place" (C++11 standard, 3.6.3/2) since they have static storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

I see several ways to do that at build time (but with the help of mechanisms beyond just the compiler/linker).

#### Pre-compile: [Use gcc's dependency generator.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-M-1043)

gcc has an option to walk the include tree for each file on the command line and list its dependencies, among them the directly or indirectly included header files. Obviously this needs gcc, but it won't actually compile anything, so it could be a pre-build command in VS with a cygwin gcc. Probably only minimal configuration is necessary because the option `-MG` lets gcc handle "missing" headers gracefully. (In order to follow nested includes it will be necessary to use `-I` in order to define include paths.)

As an example let's assume we have three files.
1.c:

```
#include "header1.h"
```

2.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "2.h"
```

and 2.h:

```
#include "header2.h"
```

Sample session:

```
$ ls && echo "-------" && gcc -MM -MG *.c
1.c  2.c  2.h
-------
1.o: 1.c header1.h
2.o: 2.c 2.h header2.h
```

This can be simply grepped for the header names.

#### Compile time:

#### Define a C preprocessor token during the build and check it in the headers

Agree on two well-known tokens, of which exactly one will be defined by the build environment for any build; the headers check against them with an `#ifdef`. For example, `header1.h` could contain the line

```
#ifdef USE_HEADER2
#   error "Using header1.h although USE_HEADER2 is defined"
#endif
```

In a make environment one could define `USE_HEADER2` by passing a `-D` option, like `make -DUSE_HEADER_1` ...` or the like. In Visual Studio one would define the symbol in the Build properties of the project.

This will not work for incremental builds, because between builds the setting might change. That is surely a source of errors; only doing complete rebuilds as a remedy is prohibitive for large projects.

#### Post-Compile: Define a static string in each header and grep the binaries for it

This is inspired by @MSalters' suggestion in the comments, but possibly a bit simpler. Define a distinct static string in each header. For `header1.h`, that could be

```
volatile static char str[] = "HEADER_1_INCLUDED";
```

(Without the `volatile` the compiler would dismiss the never-used string when built with optimization. This could be implementation specific. I used gcc 4.9.3.)

After a build you just check all library and object files for both strings and fail if both are there:

```
 if grep -q  "HEADER_1_INCLUDED" *.o *.a *.lib *.dll &&  grep -q  "HEADER_2_INCLUDED" *.o *.a *.lib *.dll; 
 then handle_error; 
 fi
```